# PostgreSQL 13 FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-13

I'm getting authentication error like below with a right password I put during the installation.

Read similar questions and answers but couldn't find a working solution for version 13.

Tried empty password and all default passwords too.
Can someone please help?

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not initiate GSSAPI security context: The operation or option is not available
could not initiate GSSAPI security context: Credential for asked mech-type mech not found in the credential handle
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

My `/Library/PostgreSQL/13/data/pg_hba.conf`:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            peer
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 peer
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            peer
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 peer
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the connection request, and which client are you using? What is the line in the PostgreSQL log that belongs to that failed connection attempt?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm trying to connect a server via pgadmin4. psql logging in also not working with an error "psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Comment: FYI, tried to change the method `scram-sha-256` in `pg_hba.conf` to `trust` -- didn't work, to `peer` -- didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It gets resolved with the config I uploaded once I **reboot** my computer.

Comment: Which config are you referring to? Did it work when you changed it to `trust` and reboot the computer or when you changed it to `peer` and reboot the computer? Also, did using `scram-sha-256` work at all in the future?